# `mvn test` works, but `mvn -Dtest=MyTest#myTestMethod test` gives an error

Tags: java, maven, testing, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to run tests via maven from my command terminal. Here's the version I'm using:

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

My project also uses java 11. When I run

`mvn test`

all the tests run properly. But when I try to run a single test method via:

`mvn -Dtest=MyTest#myTestMethod test`

Suddenly I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project holocron-service: Compilation failure
> [ERROR] javac: invalid flag: --release
> [ERROR] Usage: javac  
> [ERROR] use -help for a list of possible options

I'm using version `3.8.1` of the `maven-compiler-plugin` which should be the latest, and I've tried all the versions up to `3.6.0` with no success.

Anyway, why does it work with `mvn test`, but not `mvn -Dtest=MyTest#myTestMethod test`? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you say for sure that `MyTest#myTestMethod` is being executed in `mvn test`? Does the execution log for this class appears in the console? If you put the annotation `@Test` but import the wrong `Test` class then It won't run in `mvn test`,  this problem was happening to me some time ago. If this is not it then it would be nice if you could include your code in the question.

Comment: You use Java 8 to run the Maven (as indicated by the Java version: 1.8.0_252). Do you see the same error when running Maven with Java 11?

Comment: hm I see. How do I change the version of Java that I'm running with Maven? `java --version` shows java 11 for me.